# HP Laptop microphone not picking up any sound

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone

I have a HP ENVY laptop 13-ah0xxx & all of a sudden today my microphone is no longer working. I can hear people on zoom calls but they can't hear me, I have tried skype as well & the same problem.

Last week I added an extra monitor as I'm working from home. I had no issues making calls via zoom or skype but today nothing.

In Sound > Recording I can see Microphone Array (Realtek (R) Audio) set as the default device and a tick within a green cirle. The bars next to it don't pick up any sound & I can't even seem to test it.

Any help would be great

Comment: It could easily have a hardware problem. Get an External Microphone and try that. If that works, the internal microphone has a hardware issue.

Comment: I have some pixel ear buds that I have tried using, I can hear stuff but the other person can't hear me, so does this mean its an hardware issue?

Comment: Very likely hardware from your description.